# How to sort in accordance to best match on the results returned by a views filter?

Tags: search, views

I have a search functionality which lets user search for people based on their names. To achieve this I am using a view with an exposed filter on the field and the operator being "Contains any word". Now I want to sort the results with the best matched result appearing first. Say I am searching "Amy Jackson", I get all the users with "Amy" first and then the results with "Jackson", thus Amy Jackson does not appear first.

Comment: View filters are binary: something fits or it does not. There is no concept of "better" in them. In your question, you don't say what you consider "best", either.

Comment: Makes sense. From what i understand it first searches for data matching the first word and then searches for data matching the second word and then the results are returned in the same order. Best would be the data common between these two.

Comment: However it works, all it returns in the end is `(boolean) false` and it would require a total change in architecture to allow it return `(float) 37%` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you have the core search module installed.  For your filter use "Search terms" (exposed), and for sort use "Search score" (descending).

You'll be able to influence what factors are dominant in the ordering of results by adjusting the settings at admin/config/search/settings.

If you want more control over the ordering then it could be worth looking into the [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) module but setting this up is a lot more involved.